# How to log bean validation (jsr-303) messages when using log4j and hibernate validator?

Tags: log4j, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I am not sure how to log bean validation messages when using **log4j** and **hibernate validator**.

I tried using a "org.hibernate.validator" category in log4j resulting in a runtime exception...

I also tried using "javax.validation" category in log4j; however nothing gets logged.

Can anyone please help?

Regards,

Edit: Here is my log4j config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d: %5p (%F:%L) %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="output.log"/>
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="2000KB"/>
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="5"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p %c - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <category name="org.apache.tapestry5">
        <priority value="INFO"/>
    </category>
    <category name="com.bignibou">
        <priority value="DEBUG"/>
    </category>
      <category name="org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl">
    <priority value="TRACE"/>
</category>
    <root>
        <priority value="WARN"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the [log4j binding](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/) for sl4f on your classpath? You might also have a look at the [`log4j.properties` file](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/master/hibernate-validator/src/test/resources/log4j.properties) used for tests in Hibernate Validator.

Comment: thanks. Here is what I tried. However, it does not log anything... Any other idea?